# Can I use current Timestamp as UUID in PostgreSQL 8.2

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, uuid

I know that `PostgreSQL 9+` has module to generate `UUID`. But after a lot of search I couldn't find any solution to generate `UUID` in `PostgreSQL 8.2`. I also need to keep this version because lot of my customers are still using `8.2`. I am thinking to use current `Timestamp` as `UUID`.

Running `select extract(epoch from now());` query and getting a `Timestamp` like `1384396600.53923`. I want to store it as `character` and use as `UUID`. Is there any possibility of generating duplicate `Timestamp`? Also will it be feasible to use `Timestamp` as `UUID`?

Comment: Sorry to ask but what is serial?

Comment: A [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) is not a set of arbitrary bits. Some bits have meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure it is feasible.
but i suggest you not to use the Timestamp as UUID.

i don't konw how large concurrent your condition is.
if you are in a very much large concurrent condition,or in a very extreme condition by chance,i think it must will be give you two same  Timestamp,so there will be something wrong,right?

so,use some other way to make a "UUID".